# remember me using cakephp3

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.x

I have an error when i executed this code 
My error was **Call to a member function read() on boolean** 
 This is the code of function login :

```
 public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            if ($this->request->data['rememberMe']=="on") {

                $cookie = [];
                $cookie['username'] = $this->request->data['email'];
                $cookie['password'] = $this->request->data['password'];
                $this->Cookie->write('rememberMe', $cookie, true, "1 week");
                unset($this->request->data['rememberMe']);
            }
            if (empty($this->data)) {
                $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('rememberMe');
                if (!is_null($cookie)) {
                    $this->request->data = $cookie;
                    $user = $this->Auth->identify();
                    if ($user) {
                        $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                    } else {
                        $this->Cookie->destroy('rememberMe'); # delete invalid cookie

                        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid cookie');
                        $this->redirect('login');
                    }
                }
            }

            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        else
        $this->Flash->error(__("Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect, essayez de nouveau."));
    }
}
```

I changed `data['rememberMe']=="on"`data['rememberMe']==1` 
Another error was shown **Call to a member function write() on boolean**

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Ikbel you have try to add a `Cookie` Component in your `AppController.php` ?

```
  public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Cookie');
    }
```

Doc : [Cookie — CakePHP Cookbook 3.x documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/cookie.html)

if in your template login you use checkbox replace `$this->request->data['rememberMe']=="on"` to `$this->request->data['rememberMe'] == 1`

And replace `$this->Cookie->destroy` to `$this->Cookie->delete`

For your error :
Call to a member function setFlash() on boolean '$this->Session->setFlash('Invalid cookie');'

replace for : $this->Flash->error(**('Invalid cookie'));
$this->Flash->error(**("Username or password incorrect, try again."));

Comment: Hi @Bed0skil  i added the cookie component in may AppController

Comment: Hi @Ikbel, if you need use `cookies` now is good, but if you want logged your users look it `$this->loadComponent('Auth');` [Authentication CakePHP3](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html) it will automatically create the `Auth` cookie. Look this complete [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

Comment: Hi , My problem doesn't logging to my users , i want when i click in checkbox "remember me" the username and password are stored to the next log in

Comment: What is your current error ? **Call to a member function write() on boolean** ?

Comment: the error was changed to **Call to a member function setFlash() on boolean**  '$this->Session->setFlash('Invalid cookie');'

Comment: For your error :
`Call to a member function setFlash() on boolean '$this->Session->setFlash('Invalid cookie');' ` replace with this  : `$this->Flash->error(__('Invalid cookie'));
$this->Flash->error(__("Username or password incorrect, try again."));`

Comment: thanks a lot !! no error :)  but it didn't work I inscpected the code in the rubrique of resources i see the file of cookie of my application i find the user.username and user.password are stored but when i try to connect  the forms of login didn't shown the stored parameters in cookies ......i'm sorry for my english

Comment: Do you want use a plugin of CakePHP : [FriendsOfCake] (https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/authenticate/tree/cake3#cookieauthenticate) You haven't find a simple flash error, i think you have a skills problem PHP. You can use a best plugin or back to CakePHP Book